# Are there uses of std::forward, where the argument is not a variable name?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, perfect-forwarding

In most cases the *type* of `std::forward`'s argument is a forwarding reference:

```
template <class T>
void CallF(T&& value) {
    F(std::forward<T>(value));
}
```

In rarer cases the *type* is not a forwarding reference (`FWD` is taken from [P0644](https://wg21.link/P0644)):

```
#define FWD(x)  std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)

template <class T>
struct Wrapper {
    void operator()(T x1, T& x2, T&& x3) const {
        f(FWD(x1), FWD(x2), FWD(x3));
    }

    void (*f)(T, T&, T&&);
};
```

But, in both cases the *argument itself* is the name of a variable (`value`, `x1`, `x2`, `x3`). Are there cases where it is not a variable name, but some other expression?

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I've created a pointer to an argument, then needed to forward `*p` as the value category of the original argument. Something like:

```cpp
extern "C" void external_library(void callback(void*), void* data);

template<typename F>
void cpp_wrap(F&& f) {
    auto* pf = std::addressof(f);
    void(* callback)(void* data) = [](void* pf){
        std::forward<F>(*static_cast<std::add_pointer_t<F>>(pf))();
    };
    external_library(callback, pf);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, since you cannot capture `f`, you must pass an expression as an argument to `std::forward`. I have been thinking. The line in your lambda is itself a good library feature: dereferencing a `void*` and forwarding it to the proper value category in one function: [`my_std::void_ptr_to_ref<F>()`](https://godbolt.org/z/3jMfc5qKe).

Answer (score -1):

Check out https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward -- in particular, the "transforming wrapper".

I haven't used something like that (yet?) -- but a lot of the related stuff is still the black belt category for me.

Comment: That "transforming wrapper" converts an lvalue into an lvalue, an xvalue into an xvalue and a prvalue into an xvalue. It's pretty useless, and actively harmful in that it materializes a temporary

Comment: The "transforming wrapper" can be simplified ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vr6vnnv1a)), and in the simpler version there is no `std::forward` with an argument other than a variable name.